# Spark streaming connecting to S3 gives socket timeout

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, proxy, spark-streaming

I'm trying to run a Spark streaming app from my local to connect to an S3 bucket and am running into a `SocketTimeoutException`. This is the code to read from the bucket:

```
val sc: SparkContext = createSparkContext(scName)
val hadoopConf=sc.hadoopConfiguration
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(time))
val lines = ssc.textFileStream("s3a://foldername/subfolder/")
lines.print()
```

This is the error I get:

```
com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient executeHelper - Unable to execute HTTP request: connect timed out
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
```

I thought it might be due to the proxy so I ran my spark-submit with the proxy options like so:

```
    spark-submit --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=
-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyserver.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=9000" 
--class application.jar s3module 5 5 SampleApp
```

That still gave me the same error. Perhaps I'm not setting the proxy properly? Is there a way to set it in the code in SparkContext's conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's specific options for proxy setup, [covered in the docs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Genaral_S3A_Client_configuration)

```
<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.proxy.host</name>
  <description>Hostname of the (optional) proxy server for S3 connections.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.s3a.proxy.port</name>
  <description>Proxy server port. If this property is not set
    but fs.s3a.proxy.host is, port 80 or 443 is assumed (consistent with
    the value of fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled).</description>
</property>
```

Which can be set in spark defaults with the spark.hadoop prefix

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.proxy.host=myproxy
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.proxy.port-8080
```